# JEST Test suite failed to run: TypeError: (0 , _reactRedux.connect) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme, jestjs

So I want to test react components, and I just added testing library Enzyme and Jest, try to setup tests. But I got an error which come from my node modules if I import a component in my test code.

My app is using: React + Webpack + Babel. 
I have `"react": "^0.14.8"`,`"enzyme": "^3.3.0",`, `"enzyme-adapter-react-14": "^1.0.5"` , `"jest": "^22.4.2"` , `"webpack": "^3.8.1"` , and `"node": "5.6.0"`.

I installed Enzyme & Jest, wrote simple test like this and passed.

```
import enzyme, {shallow} from 'enzyme';

describe('Testing test', () => {
  it('This test will always pass!', () => {
    const test = "test"
    expect(test).to.have.length(4);
  })
})
```

This is Fine. BUT when I import components, just import, not even use it, I got an error: 
(UPDATE: I feel the `moduleNameMapper` in package.json isn't correct)

```
import DealList from './DealList';


Test suite failed to run

TypeError: (0 , _reactRedux.connect) is not a function

  35 |         case("integer"):
  36 |           return integer
> 37 |         case("required, integer"):
  38 |           return [required, integer]
  39 |       }
  40 |     }

  at createConnectedField (node_modules/redux-form/lib/ConnectedField.js:329:43)
  at createField (node_modules/redux-form/lib/createField.js:48:53)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/redux-form/lib/Field.js:17:45)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/redux-form/lib/index.js:122:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/CreateDealForm/CreateFundDealForm.js:37:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/index.js:24:28)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/containers/DealList/DealList.js:35:19)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/containers/DealList/DealList.test.js:7:17)
```

This is my package.json

```
"scripts" :{
   ...
    "test": "jest"
},
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>test/setup.js",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "components(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components"
    },
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/redux-form/"
   ]
}
```

my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "stage-0", "react"],

  "plugins": [
  "syntax-dynamic-import",
  "dynamic-import-node",
  "transform-runtime",
  "add-module-exports",
  "transform-decorators-legacy",
  "transform-react-display-name"
  ],

  "env": {
    "development": {
    "plugins": [
    "typecheck",
    ["react-transform", {
        "transforms": [{
            "transform": "react-transform-catch-errors",
            "imports": ["react", "redbox-react"]
             }
         ]
       }]
    ]
  },
 "test": {
  "presets": ["env", "stage-0", "react"]
   }
 }
}
```

my test/setup.js

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-14'
import { expect } from 'chai';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
global.expect = expect;
```

Any thoughts would be awesome. Thank you!

Comment: If you are using Jest then why are you using expect from chai?

Comment: @VivekN I just figured out that Jest has `expect` as well. Does that matter?

Comment: Ideally it shouldn't affect the code as such, but let's remove anything that's not needed. So remove that global expect chai entry and the try the code again

Comment: @VivekN I removed it but errors are the same. I figured out that the `moduleNameMapper` on package.json is wrong, I changed to  `"^components(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components$1"` and I got ride of this error. And got another one which asks me to install the legacy decorators transform, But it is already installed. I will close this question, since it is solved. And try to figure out the new one. Thank you! If you have thoughts about the new bug, that will be very helpful! Thanks again!

Comment: Great, good to know that it got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the `moduleNameMapper` on package.json is wrong.
This is correct:

```
"jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>test/setup.js",
     "moduleNameMapper": {
         "^components(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components$1"
     },
    "verbose": true
 },
```

And got another one which asks me to install the legacy decorators transform, but it is already installed. I will close this question.

Comment: All I had to do was `rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock && yarn`. Just updated a very custom cra v3 app to cra v4. Jest 26.